# How to inject resources into EJB3 beans with Spring 2.5?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

If I create an EJB3 bean (say a stateless session bean) in an application using Spring 2.5 for DI, how should I inject dependencies from Spring into the bean without coupling the bean to Spring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you consider applying an interceptor as coupling but that's to my knowledge the standard approach. From the [Chapter 18. Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/ejb.html) of the documentation:

> #### [18.3.2. EJB 3 injection interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/ejb.html#ejb-implementation-ejb3)
>
> For EJB 3 Session Beans and
>   Message-Driven Beans, Spring provides
>   a convenient interceptor that resolves
>   Spring 2.5's `@Autowired` annotation
>   in the EJB component class:
>   `org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor`.
>   This interceptor can be applied
>   through an
>   `@Interceptors`
>   annotation in the EJB component class,
>   or through an interceptor-binding XML
>   element in the EJB deployment
>   descriptor.
>
> ```
> @Stateless
> @Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
> public class MyFacadeEJB implements MyFacadeLocal {
>
>     // automatically injected with a matching Spring bean
>     @Autowired
>     private MyComponent myComp;
>
>     // for business method, delegate to POJO service impl.
>     public String myFacadeMethod(...) {
>         return myComp.myMethod(...);
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` by
>   default obtains target beans from a
>   `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator`,
>   with the context defined in a bean
>   definition file named
>   `beanRefContext.xml`. By default, a
>   single context definition is expected,
>   which is obtained by type rather than
>   by name. However, if you need to
>   choose between multiple context
>   definitions, a specific locator key is
>   required. The locator key (i.e. the
>   name of the context definition in
>   `beanRefContext.xml`) can be
>   explicitly specified either through
>   overriding the
>   `getBeanFactoryLocatorKey` method in a
>   custom
>   `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor`
>   subclass.

The only other option I'm aware of (extending the EJB 2.x support classes) is much worse from a coupling point of view (and thus doesn't answer your question).

#### See also

- [Default  Injecting Spring bean to EJB3 SLSB without @Autowired Annotation](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=68195)